Convert source data to DATE in Teradata
I have following values in the source column which is Varchar type.


45307.9316203704



-15



19.62



20000



As per the requirement, above values need to be converted to date in Teradata.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Those values certainly don't appear to be dates. Is the intent to convert (other) values that really are dates to DATE type and to have these incorrect values converted to NULL? That could likely be done but we would need more information about the "good" values.
